# libreoffice calc -copy paste not working

Tags: libreoffice

when i copy the entire page from websites to libre office spreadsheet it doest not copy correctly ...please help me i dont want to uninstall ubuntu to previous window 7 as i love it

website which i trying is---http://164.100.181.140/fcs/Helpline/NFSA/ReportRegidWise.aspx?val=NSMxMzgjVSMwOTEzODAwNzM0ODAwNzE2I1gjMTAwMTAwMzAwMDM4I0JQTCMwOTEzODAwNzM0ODAwNzE2

Comment: Use: Edit --  Paste Special

Comment: I had the same problem. Paste Special didn't help. Pasting into Gedit and re-copying didn't help (I thought it might remove/show anything funky the clipboard grabbed from the website). Pasting into Writer and re-copying worked.